# Number of ordered combinations with minimum value

Tags: combinatorics

I have n elements, say $\{1,2,...,n\}$. Consider all ordered k-combinations of these elements. For example for n = 3 and k = 2 we have 9:
$(1,1), (1,2), (2,1), (1,3), (3,1), (2,2), (2,3), (3,2), (3,3)$

I believe the formula for the number of ordered combinations for any n and any k is $\frac{n!}{(n-k)!} + n$.

For a given n and a given k I want to know how many of those k-combinations have a minimum of exactly i, where $i \in \{1,2,...,n\}$

For the example above:
if $i=1$ we have 5(the first 5), if $i=2$ we have 3 and for $i=n$ we always have 1.

Comment: For the number of ordered combinations, why isn't it just $n^k$?  $n$ independent choices for each of $k$ slots...

Comment: You're right, it's $n^k$.

Comment: Ok....well, the same counting method works for your minimum. If $N_i$ is the number with minimum AT LEAST $i$ then $N_i=(n-(i-1))^k$.  Your value is $N_i-N_{i+1}$.

Comment: Makes sense. Thank you!

Comment: What if we generalize to N elements each of them taking a different number of values. So instead of $n^k$ choices we'd have $n1 * n2 * ... *nn$. How can I find the number then ?

Comment: I don't understand.  if you know the available options at each stage, then just impose the minimum condition as before.